# How can I disable the automatic edge flip when dragging a window to the left/right edge?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce, window-management

In Xubuntu, when using only *one* desktop, dragging windows to the left/right edge scales the windows to the left/right half of the desktop.

However, when using *multiple* desktops this does not work because there is an edge flip to the adjacent desktop instead.

How can I disable the automatic edge flip in Xubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'Window Manager' settings, under the 'Advanced' tab, disable *'Wrap workspaces when dragging a window off the screen'*

[image]